# MySQL age from date of birth - TIMESTAMPDIFF()

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

Yes very similar has been asked before, but bear with me.

Now there are many functions people come up with to determine an accurate age from date of birth taking into account leap years and whatnot. However the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html) offers a very simple solution:

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age`

This seems to work for all the dates I throw at it. However the documentation states nothing about the correctness of this or how it calculates the difference. It does seem to be smarter than a simple `diff/365.25`.

Here's some examples:

```
('1992-08-12', '3009-08-12') => 1017 - Correct
('1992-08-12', '3009-08-11') => 1016 - Correct
('1992-02-29', '3009-03-01') => 1017 - Correct
('1992-02-29', '3009-02-28') => 1016 - Correct
```

Looks pretty correct to me and that is a heck of a long time for minor miscalculations to stack up in.

My question to you, is it safe to use this? Can you provide a set of dates this will give an incorrect result for? (Not interested in units smaller than a day)

Comment: If the documentation says that it calculates the difference, and all your tests confirm it, why do you doubt it? If there were caveats, I think it would say so.

Comment: It probably uses something like the algorithm here: http://alcor.concordia.ca/~gpkatch/gdate-algorithm.html

Comment: @Barmar because it is widely ignored in other posts around the web in favour of larger more complex algorithms. My tests are in no way definitive (I don't know what to test for). Just because it is in documentation doesn't mean it is totally accurate, bugs exist, they could of thought "it is good enough" but my good enough is different. I like facts, not to guess.

Comment: @GeorgeReith If you want to be 100% sure open and go through mysql sources.

Comment: @peterm I don't use `C` or `C++` and the point is I don't know what constitutes a fully accurate algorithm (Dates are complex, what with so many different calendars, popes removing days, .etc) - totally unfeasible. A mere list of dates to test against would suffice, this information must be out there somewhere, people must be writing test suites for date functions.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Then unfortunately all you have left with is to trust documentation and keep up with bug reports on http://bugs.mysql.com. Everything else won't be fact-based.

Comment: @peterm That's not true, if one can test it against all the valid edge cases it is a reasonable assertion that it works, I just need to know what they are (although I only really care about the last 30 years onwards into the future - so Pope Gregory doesn't matter). Even the comments in the documentation lead me to have doubts as they all argue over different methods to implement it - the issue is that we are never 100% accurate it is about knowing up to what point the creator thought it was an acceptable inaccuracy.

Comment: @GeorgeReith How about all other functions (at least datetime ones)? Are you willing to test them too? Anyways good luck. I truly wish you find your answer to the question.

Comment: @peterm Thanks. They need to be combined to make an algorithm, for which many have already been disproved. I do believe this sort of information should be in the documentation, a simple it is safe to use x for y or x fails if y can cut down on a lot of ambiguity, I'm sure they have rigorous tests for these at Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There has been bugs, but you should feel safe to use it if you have latest say 6 years MySQL version or so :)

```
some earlier bugs e.g. month diff of dates:
TS1 = '2006-01-21 19:52:05'
TS2 = '2007-01-21 18:30:14'

which gave 0, and not 12.
```

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16697

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25994